# React State giving undefined, new to react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, websocket, django-channels

I'm new to react-native, I have been working on a simple app but for some reason I keep getting (undefined) for some of my states, also when fetching data the server is getting called multiple times with value (undefined) before returning an actual value. I have been searching for quite long but didn't find anything that helped so I came here to ask for help from more advance React developers than me.

my code looks like this:

```
const { data: chat, loading } = useApi(chatApi.getChat, { chatId: chatId, channelId: route.params.channelId });
const chatMessages = chat.messages  // I declared this only for testing
const [messages, setMessages] = useState(chatMessages);
console.log("Chat Messages: " + chatMessages)
console.log("messages State: " + messages)
```

In the terminal I get:

```
Chat Messages: undefined
messages State: undefined
Chat Messages: undefined
messages State: undefined
Chat Messages: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
messages State: undefined
```

Also, why does the 'chat' variable is being rendered multiple times with value (undefined) before giving an actual value? This caused the backend WS server to be called multiple times with no reason causing worse performance

useApi hook:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const useApi = (apiFunc, funcParams ={}) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [error, setError] = useState(false);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    const fetchData = async () => {
        setLoading(true);
        const response = await apiFunc(funcParams);
        setLoading(false);
        if (!response.ok) return setError(true);
        setData(response.data);
    };
    useEffect(() => { fetchData() }, []);
    if (data) return { data, setData, error, loading, setLoading };
};

export default useApi;
```

#### full code

:

```
const chatId = route.params.chat.id;
    const { data: chat, loading } = useApi(chatApi.getChat, { chatId: chatId, channelId: route.params.channelId });
    const { user } = useAuth();
    const [text, setText] = useState(() => { return ""; });
    const chatMessages = chat.messages  // I declared this only for testing
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState(chatMessages);
    console.log("Chat Messages: " + chatMessages)
    console.log("messages State: " + messages)

    const chatSocket = new WebSocket(`${settings.wsUrl}chat/${chatId}/?userId=${user.id}`);
    

    // Join & Leave Room
    useEffect(() => {
        chatSocket.onmessage = e => {
            const data = JSON.parse(e.data);
            setMessages([...messages, data.message]);
        };
        return () => {
            chatSocket.close(0);
        };
    }, []);

    const handleSendMessage = () => {
        chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
            text: text,
        }));
        setText("");
    };

    return (
        <>
            ...
        </>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're getting undefined while the data is loading (as the data isn't there yet and it's therefore undefined), you're printing the value of the variable whenever the component renders regardless of if the data has loaded yet.

You have access to a loading indicator: `const { data: chat, loading }` but you're not using the loading variable for anything conditional. Something like

```
if (!loading && data != null) {
   console.log("Chat Messages: " + chatMessages)
   console.log("messages State: " + messages)
   const chatSocket = new WebSocket(`${settings.wsUrl}chat/${chatId}/?userId=${user.id}`);
}
```

Comment: Ok this solved getting rendered multiple times, but why the messages state always give undefined while the chatMessages variable gave a value once

Comment: useState is a React hook that preserves state between renders. That means that the first time you render it, you give it `chatMessages` as the input (chatMessages is undefined on first render as it hasn't loaded yet).

When the component re-renders, React remembers the state of chatMessages (undefined) and doesn't reset it. You need to call setMessages once it's loaded. You could do that a few ways. Inside an onEffect with loading as a dependency, or you could just remove useState and have it as a variable if you don't need it as state